# How to identify cycles in a huge directed graph?

Tags: algorithm

There is a huge N edges on directed graph.

i have fix memory, such as 128MB.  actually the graph size is GB or more.

you can't put them into memory, so you can cache it to disk, how can we more effectively access the file?

if what you load part into memory, actually it has cycle in the rest without memory.

how to solve this ?

Remember it is huge N with fixed memory.

Comment: More effectively than what? What's wrong with the usual algorithms? Increasing the number of edges doesn't really do anything horrible to their space consumption. Is the graph itself too big to hold in memory? And what kind of equipment are we working with, here? A cluster? One PC with the graph on disk? We need more details.

Comment: ok, let me add more detailed information

Comment: is it good to understanding? we need to have effective data cache in file

Comment: or, do we have other solution, such as index file or other big data solution? i am not expert so anyone can help?